# Prevent centring on focused input in hidden overflow area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It is hard to explain with words so here's a fiddle I made to explain the problem better: http://jsfiddle.net/j2zurbbv/1/. When the first timeout fires the container div is not 'scrolled' which is the behaviour I want. However when the input is outside of the visible part of the div (as it is with the second timeout) the container div centres about this input.

Container css:

```
#container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
}
```

For the record I have only tested this on Chrome 37.0

Comment: what good would it be to focus an element user can't see? Really not clear what your expectations are or what you consider is a problem here

Comment: @charlietfl I want to scroll the contents of the overflow hidden div to the correct location by changing the 'top' value and use css transitions. The fact that the browser overrides this transition and jerks to the place that the input is is the problem. Also scrolling is an undesirable behaviour when a div is set to overflow. I want to focus on the <input> without the div scrolling.

Comment: well you could try to animate the container and then focus

Comment: Yeah that's what I currently do but using a timeout to focus the element after a 400ms animation is far from ideal - what if someone clicks on another input during those 400ms - then they will quickly and for no reason be pulled to the first element. I just want a way of properly disabling scrolling on this div (which I thought overflow:hidden does) but apparently this overrides it.

Comment: could mask it with some sort of loading indicator, or disable all inputs. Not knowing what this UI is used for or what will trigger these scroll events it's tricky to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to work it out. Counter the scrolling that the browser does by doing `document.getElementById('container').scrollTop = 0;` whenever you programatically focus on an element outside of the visible area of an `overflow: hidden` div AND whenever a user inputs in such an element. Demonstrative JSFiddle (without prevention of input scrolling) http://jsfiddle.net/j2zurbbv/2/.